# Why is there a None in output?

Tags: python, recursion, output

Help, I'm trying to create a function that uses modulus to print numbers that are divisible by an integer, in this case, multiples of 17:

```
def nextDivisible(n):
    if n % 17 == 0:
        print n
    else:
        nextDivisible(n+1)
```

But the output is for example:

```
n: 93 next divisible:  102
None
n: 59 next divisible:  68
None
```

Why is there a None?! and how do I remove it, thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you call the function like this: `print(nextDivisible(n))` Please remove the `print` and do it again. Btw, your problem is caused by code you haven't even included.

Comment: n is a random integer

Comment: Yeah, this can't be all of the code.  There's nothing showing that prints "next divisible".

Comment: Thanks but I think you badly missed my point.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, I cant show the rest of the code cause that code is behind the program. Im not allowed to see it... Maybe another way of pursuing the problem could fix the problem?

Comment: You didn't share your full code, and the code you did share has indentation problems, but maybe you're trying to do something like `print(nextDivisible(n))`? If so, it makes sense that you're seeing `None`, since `nextDivisible()` doesn't return any values. If you can't share your actual code, you must create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example in accordance with the rules on here. Otherwise there's not enough info for anyone to help you.

Comment: OK - check the indentation on your function.  Also, do you have the text that describes what your function is supposed to do?

Comment: Nothing that has been said has worked so far, thing is that the description of the problem is in finnish, I can translate that.

Define a recursive function in the nextDivisible(n) that assumes the integer as a parameter and returns a first integer greater than or equal to n and is divisible by 17. For example, nextDivisible(16) returns 17 .
The structure of the function must be recursive

Comment: Ah, a homework question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are printing out the result instead of returning it from the function.

If you change your code to be like this it should fix it:

```
def nextDivisible(n):
    if n % 17 == 0:
        return n
    return nextDivisible(n + 1)
```

How this works with recursion is that your function `nextDivisible` is going to be repeatedly called until it reaches its base case of `n` being divisible by `17`. When that case occurs it will return `n` all the way back up the recursive stack to where the original first call to the function was done.

You also don't need an else statement because `return` statements break out of the function code. But sometimes `else`'s are good for readability.

Comment: That was it!
Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to:

```
print(nextDivisible(n))
```

I think you get `None` printed because your function doesn't return anything. It is also redundant to print the return of the function because you print the numbers inside the loop.

All you need is:

```
nextDivisible(n)
```

And it will print the divisible numbers.

If you are use `nextDivisible()` in other functions, it may be worth nothing that a return statement may be required depending on the nature of how you are using it.

For all intents and purposes this should work just fine.

And python 3.x:

```
x = [x for x in range(1000)]
def nextDivisible(x, mod=17):
    c = 0
    for n in x:
        if n % mod == 0:
            print(n)
            c += 1
        else: 
            #nextDivisible(n+1)
            pass
    print('{} numbers divisible by {} in {}'.format(c, mod, len(x)))
nextDivisible(x)
```

Expected output:

```
59 total numbers divisible by 17 in 1000
```